# How to prevent search engines caching custom handler supplied "text/plain" type

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, handler

I have a iis handler that supplies `context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";` for .txt file
How do I prevent the content from being cached (should allow index, so I don't want to add it to robots.txt) by google or any search engine?

Is there a way I can add nocache header to `context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"`;

I have `context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);`
but this does not prevent search engines from caching the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That header controls caching on the client, not by search engines. You need to set

```
  Response.AppendHeader("X-Robots-Tag", "noarchive");
```

[Described here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag)

> Do not show a "Cached" link in search results.

Comment: Martin, you are not just a SQL expert!